# Iframe over applet flickering

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, applet

I am using a iFrame to show content over my Applet in my online game.

It work's perfectly in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc. But as always not in Internet Explorer on Windows.

When the iframe opens over the applet, the content become to "Flickering"/"Blinking" like the applet is updating a lot, which it doesn't.

What can i do? I am using this:

```
<applet id="applet" code="main.AvatarClient.class" archive="qqqqqAvatarClient.jar" name="Chat" width="760" height="582" scriptable="true" MAYSCRIPT="true" >
   <param name="cache_option" value="YES" / >
   <param name="localization" value="locDK/" />
   <param name="userName" value="<?=$user?>" />
   <param name="password" value="<?=$pass?>" />
```

And the overlay where iframe is:

```
 <div class="add-block qw no-rounded-borders" id="wo" style="position:absolute;left:756px;margin-top:-30px;z-index:99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;height:380px;width:495px;display:none;">   
            <iframe id="my" src="loading.php" frameborder="0" height="380" width="496" scrolling="no" style="z-index:9999999999999999999999999999999999;position:absolute"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you temporarily hide the applet while the iframe is open?

Comment: No, that would be a bad solution, because it's a game. And it has to show the game while iframe is over.

Comment: I don't mean remove the game, just give it `left: -999999999px` or something. Or is the iframe semi-transparent?

Comment: No, that will destroy the game.

Comment: Use HTML5/JS for the game and the problem will likely disappear.  Applets have always wreaked havoc with floating elements.

Comment: Eh, the problem is it's a bug game.

Comment: The problem here is IE. Because Java is a plug-in, IE wants to display it on top as the Java frames update. If you are unable to temporarily move the applet, then there's not really anything you can do.